# keep child fixed on the bottom of absolute parent using CSS

Tags: css, css-position

i have an absolute scrollable parent div with fixed height value, and a fixed child on the bottom of it's parent, but the child is always set in the bottom the page not it's parent

```css
    .parent{
      width:300px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color:red;
      position:absolute;
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    
    .child{
      width:300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color:green;
      position:fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div class="child">
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

**this is the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeMRZx) to see how it's look like.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `position:sticky;` to `child`

```css
    .parent{
      width:300px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color:red;
      position:absolute;
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    
    .child{
      width:100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color:green;
      position:sticky;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div class="child">
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: happy to help:)

Comment: you already used sticky in the first snippet, why repeating? both code are the same